# 'run' is not a valid command. See 'help'. when trying to run command 'spring run hello.groovy'

Tags: spring-boot

Apparently, the run is not a valid command with spring.

My path variables are correctly stored as seen in the following image.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/La3iu.png)

Spring --version command shows the correct version. (Spring CLI v3.0.1)

I am not sure what is the issue over here.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zn9tc.png)

I tried the above commands too. (This is the official spring installation doc)

However, I don't get the expected results.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AR6cI.png)

Comment: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/33482

Answer (score 0):

"run" command was deleted in 3.0.0 version

Comment: What is the equivalent command?

Comment: `mvn spring-boot:run`

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.6.RELEASE/reference/html/using-boot-running-your-application.html#using-boot-running-with-the-maven-plugin

Answer (score 0):

As other comments and answers already mentioned, with spring cli 3.0.x, the run command was removed along with some other commands.

There are already some issues on their Github page:
This issue describes your exact issue: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/33482

Which references this issue, where it was planned to remove those commands: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/32263